# Layout issues in UITableView after updating to Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode9

After I updated to Xcode 9, UITableView in iOS 10 device is behaving very strangely. The tableView cell sizes are not maintained. It it resizing by itself and not following the constraints and cell sizes I had explicitly coded. The gap between the tableView cells is black all of a sudden. However, these layout issues are not reciprocated in iOS 11 handset. 
 In a nutshell, the layout is completely screwed in iOS 10 devices. Is anyone else having backward compatibility after updating to Xcode 9? If so how did you resolve it.

To change the frame width of the custom table View cell cell I am using the frame property. The code I am using is

```
    override var frame: CGRect {

    //Decrease frame width of the tableViewCell
    get {
        return super.frame
    }
    set (newFrame) {
        var frame = newFrame
        frame.origin.x += 8
        frame.size.width = frame.size.width-16
        super.frame = frame
    }
}
```

**Below is how the tableViewCell is presented in iOS 11 which is correct** 
[image: iPhone 5s Screenshot]

**this is how the tableViewCell is presented in iOS 10 which is incorrect**

[[image: iPhone 6s screenshot[2]]

As you can see the gap from right margin to the tableView Cell is more.

Comment: I had tableview layout issues after upgrading. Not exactly as you described, but maybe it's related. In my case the main problem was, that I had not implemented estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You will need to show some code if you want anyone to be able to help. Also some screenshots would help explain what you are seeing better than a written explanation.

Comment: No one can help based on the information you have given (i.e. none). Adding a bounty doesn't improve the question.

Comment: Also, if you have sampe xcode project which reproduces your problem, please, publish it anywhere in github

Comment: @matt Please check the updated question. Sorry for leaving out the essentials. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Fogmeister Please check the updated question. Sorry for leaving out the essentials. Hope this helps.

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov Please check the updated question. Sorry for leaving out the essentials. Hope this helps.

Comment: "To change the frame width of the custom table View cell cell I am using the frame property" Well, that's totally illegal and unsupported (and deeply bizarre). You have no business touching a cell's frame. So it is unlikely that anyone is going to help you do it. "I want the bounty winner to tell me why is this happening" It's happening because what you're doing is totally illegal and unsupported (and deeply bizarre). :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Throw away your existing code. Don't touch the cell's frame in any way.

To make cells that *look* narrower than the table, give the cell a clear background and put an opaque view inside the content view that is inset from the cell's bounds (or you could use the cell's background view for this). Use autolayout to configure this, so that it works regardless of screen size.